# Photo and Rate extracting from Google Map API

Tags: google-maps

I have a problem relating to photo, rate extraction from Google Map API.

The problem is that when I made right request I receive a response without photo\rate data inside.

Example of request:

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=ChIJvaXwAwVWwokRvmAdVdWrD4s&key=[YOUR KEY]`

The response:

```
   "html_attributions": [],
   "result": {
      "address_components": [
         {
            "long_name": "325",
            "short_name": "325",
            "types": [
               "street_number"
            ]
         },
         {
            "long_name": "Orient Way",
            "short_name": "Orient Way",
            "types": [
               "route"
            ]
         },
         {
            "long_name": "Lyndhurst",
            "short_name": "Lyndhurst",
            "types": [
               "locality",
               "political"
            ]
         },
         {
            "long_name": "Bergen County",
            "short_name": "Bergen County",
            "types": [
               "administrative_area_level_2",
               "political"
            ]
         },
         {
            "long_name": "New Jersey",
            "short_name": "NJ",
            "types": [
               "administrative_area_level_1",
               "political"
            ]
         },
         {
            "long_name": "United States",
            "short_name": "US",
            "types": [
               "country",
               "political"
            ]
         },
         {
            "long_name": "07071",
            "short_name": "07071",
            "types": [
               "postal_code"
            ]
         },
         {
            "long_name": "2008",
            "short_name": "2008",
            "types": [
               "postal_code_suffix"
            ]
         }
      ],
      "adr_address": "<span class=\"street-address\">325 Orient Way</span>, <span class=\"locality\">Lyndhurst</span>, <span class=\"region\">NJ</span> <span class=\"postal-code\">07071-2008</span>, <span class=\"country-name\">USA</span>",
      "formatted_address": "325 Orient Way, Lyndhurst, NJ 07071, USA",
      "geometry": {
         "location": {
            "lat": 40.80528109999999,
            "lng": -74.1147282
         },
         "viewport": {
            "northeast": {
               "lat": 40.80654243029149,
               "lng": -74.1131421697085
            },
            "southwest": {
               "lat": 40.80384446970849,
               "lng": -74.1158401302915
            }
         }
      },
      "icon": "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/geocode-71.png",
      "id": "916e480f4ad34516acae418957c8c75e6bb6deea",
      "name": "325 Orient Way",
      "place_id": "ChIJvaXwAwVWwokRvmAdVdWrD4s",
      "reference": "ChIJvaXwAwVWwokRvmAdVdWrD4s",
      "scope": "GOOGLE",
      "types": [
         "premise"
      ],
      "url": "https://maps.google.com/?q=325+Orient+Way,+Lyndhurst,+NJ+07071,+USA&ftid=0x89c2560503f0a5bd:0x8b0fabd5551d60be",
      "utc_offset": -300,
      "vicinity": "Lyndhurst"
   },
   "status": "OK"
}
```

The address of this place is: *325 ORIENT WAY, LYNDHURST, NJ, 07071*.

If you try to find this address in Google Map, you will find the place with list of places, like this:

[image]

After that, if you select the first item from underlined list from previous photo you will find the place with photos and rates, like this:

[image]

The link on first screenshot of place: [Google Map place link](https://www.google.com/maps/place/325+Orient+Way,+Lyndhurst,+NJ+07071,+USA/@40.8052851,-74.1169169,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x89c2560503f0a5bd:0x8b0fabd5551d60be!8m2!3d40.8052811!4d-74.1147282).

**Questions:**

1. What do you think, is it smth wrong in my request? (following Google Map API documentation, i could not find any issues regarding the request);
2. As you may see on my first screenshot, we have a list with locations and only second one have photos\rate. Can it be the case that Google Map API select the first one, does not see photos\rates and just remove it from the response? But if so, I don't know how to change my request in order to select first locale with photos\rates or launch it in more flexible way.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I found what is the problem.
The problem in place ID. In the request I used place ID for business (you can check the "type" of the response). It means that in the request i linked on object which have some location-items inside. And **this obkject** does not have any data like photo\rate.

I found that way how to extract the right place ID.

If you have the address of **this object** (in my case, the address is: *325 ORIENT WAY, LYNDHURST, NJ, 07071*) and the name of the shop which you looking for (in my case it is: *Frank's GMC*) you can create the next two request. First - in order to extract the place ID, and the second - to extract all needed data.

1. `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/json?input=Frank's GMC, 325 ORIENT WAY, LYNDHURST, NJ, 07071&inputtype=textquery&key=[YOUR KEY]`
   there you need to put shop name and address separated by comma in to **input** param
2. `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=ChIJ_8hLBQVWwokRY1uywGWl8vs&key=[YOUR KEY]`
   this you need to use the place id from response on first request.